# Keeping Angular form validation DRY

Tags: angularjs, validation, dry

I have a form that has maybe 15-20 fields. Each one of them contains an attribute that looks something like this:

```
ng-class='addressForm.city.$invalid && addressForm.city.$touched ? "error" : ""'
```

So I have that long string of code repeated 15-20 times. This sets my DRY alarm bells off bigtime.

I could devise my own way to make this more DRY but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Is there a gererally-accepted way of keeping Angular form validation DRY?

Comment: Can't you wrap that up in a helper of some sort?

Comment: you could check for invalid fields on submit event and then you could change that into ``ng-class="{'error': addressForm[field-name-here].invalid }"``

Comment: @DaveNewton I imagine that's a possibility. Open to suggestions as to how that might go.

Comment: @TanaseButcaru Seems like an improvement although not as big of one as I was hoping for.

Comment: if you want to make it "real-time" (to check for fields validity immediately after user changed the value) you could add ``ng-change="fieldChanged(field-name-or-id)``. Also, the ``ng-class`` attribute should be there. The only diff between this and my first solution is that you make the validation on value change, not on submit. If you want to remove the ``ng-class``, then just pass ``this`` to ``fieldChanged`` function (that would be the element's instance) and add/remove the class via ``angular.element``

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for styling use CSS.

Angular will add `.ng-invalid` and `.ng-touched` to input elements that are invalid and touched.

Or you could wrap the whole thing in a directive something like

```
angular.module('module').directive('errorClass', function(){
    return{
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, el, attr, model) {
             function setClass() {
                if(model.$touched && model.$invalid) {
                   if(!el.hasClass('error')) { 
                      el.addClass('error');
                   }
                } else {
                    el.removeClass('error');
                }
             }

             scope.$watch(function(){ return model.$touched; }, setClass);
             scope.$watch(function(){ return model.$invalid; }, setClass);
        }
    }
});
```

Also i havn't actually used this directive, so it may need some tweaking.

Comment: What are your scope.$watches watching?

Comment: The watch can take a function as its first argument instead of a string. In this case they are watching if the model has been touched or is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As @lain said, you don't have to add another class (like `error`) if the field is invalid, Angular adds that for you by default, it's just the name that differs (`ng-invalid`).
You can see how is that used [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mKlVJkvvAR8tL6wv7jz5?p=preview) (the official form example from Angular).

If you still want to do this in your way, this is the implementation of my latest comment, using `ngChange` directive.

The html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="addressForm.city" required ng-change="fieldChanged(this, 'city')">
```

The change event:

```
$scope.fieldChanged = function(el, fieldName){
   if($scope.addressForm[fieldName].$invalid && $scope.addressForm[fieldName].$touched) angular.element(el).addClass('error');
   else angular.element(el).removeClass('error');
}
```

This is not good practice (to manipulate the DOM in the controller), you should implement that in a directive, but binding a directive to each field would add watchers and I, personally, try to avoid as much as possible using too many watchers.

A more elegant option would be to combine this `ngChange` with `ngClass` or simply go with that simple DOM manipulation within controller. It's your choise :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own directive for this. I believe the following directive, when applied, will behave equivalently to this:

```
form(name='addressForm')
  input(
    type='text'
    name='city'
    ng-class='addressForm.city.$invalid && (addressForm.city.$touched || addressForm.$submitted) ? "error" : ""'
  )
```

Instead of all that, I can do:

```
form(name='addressForm')
  input(
    type='text'
    name='city'
    validate-for='addressForm'
  )
```

The directive will check validity on:

- Blur
- Form submission
- Value change

Here's the code (ES6):

```
'use strict';

class ValidateFor {
  constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = 'ngModel';

    this.link = ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) => {
      var form = $scope[$attrs.validateFor];
      var field = form[$element.attr('name')];

      $scope.$on('form-submitted', () => {
        this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
      });

      $scope.$watch(() => ngModel.$modelValue, () => {
        if (field.$touched) {
          this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
        }
      });

      $element.bind('blur', () => {
        this.checkForErrors(field, $element);
      });
    };
  }

  checkForErrors(field, $element) {
    if (field.$invalid) {
      $element.addClass('error');
    } else {
      $element.removeClass('error');
    }
  }
}

ValidateFor.$inject = [];
```

You could probably even eliminate the necessity for supplying the form name in `validate-for`. I just did it that way because I have some nested form situations.

Comment: hi, this is awesome, do you have an update to the code for Angular 8?

Answer (score 0):

[valdr](http://netceteragroup.github.io/valdr/) looks great. I haven't used it yet, but I will try it, and will update this post later.